# Showing Map Tooltip by seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple map that a tooltip will show(and hide) when clicked individually:

[image: simple map with tooltip on]

My problem is I want that tooltip to show up by a certain amount of seconds on its own without clicking. but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".states-img").click(function() {
  showtooltip = $(this).attr('location');
  $(".map-tooltip").removeClass("showtooltip");
  $("."+showtooltip+"").addClass("showtooltip");
  console.log(showtooltip);
}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of `.click()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".states-img").hover(function() {
    showtooltip = $(this).attr('location');
    $(".map-tooltip").removeClass("showtooltip");
    $("." + showtooltip + "").addClass("showtooltip");
    console.log(showtooltip);
  }, function() {
    showtooltip = $(this).attr('location');
    $("." + showtooltip + "").removeClass("showtooltip");
    $(".map-tooltip").addClass("showtooltip"); // evaluate if really needed
  });
});
```